# Call main theme function with plugin

Tags: wordpress, function, templates, plugins, themes

We created a plugin with a new template and we want to hook the main theme function and return the main plugin function.

We tried it with:

```
add_filter( "page_template", "test" );

function test( $template ) {
    if( 'plugin_name.php' == basename( $template ) )
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin_folder/plugin_name.php';
    return $template;
}
```

and changed page template in theme functions with main function of plugin which runs template inside plugin:

```
add_filter( "page_template", "main_plugin_function" );
```

Is page_template the right filter to change theme template?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `template_include` filter, this filter hook is executed immediately before WordPress includes the predetermined template file. This can be used to override WordPress's default template behavior.

For example

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'portfolio-page-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Comment: Thanks for help! I try many combinations with template_include to achieve plugin call to change template with function from plugin, but still unsuccessfully. Now i try to call plugin from child teme functions.php, whith: 
add_filter( 'template_include', 'function_from_plugin' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'function_from_plugin' ) ) {

function function_from_plugin( $template ){

    return plugins_url( __FILE__ ) . 'plugin_name/plugin.php';

}

}
    return $template;